# SQL query with subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, mysql-dependent-subquery

My data is like this:

```
data1_qqq_no_abc_ccc
data1_qqq_abc_ccc
data2_qqq_no_abc_ccc
data2_qqq_abc_ccc
data3_qqq_no_abc_ccc
data4_qqq_no_abc_ccc
data4_qqq_abc_ccc
```

...

Now I want to get the fields where data has substring _no_abc_ccc, but doesn't have _abc_ccc. In the above example, its data3

I am trying to create a query for it.
rough one is

```
select SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, 'abc', 1)  
from table1 
where SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, 'abc', 1) not LIKE "%no" 
  and NOT IN (select SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, '_no_abc', 1) 
              from table 
              where name LIKE "%no_abc");
```

Comment: Why not simply do: `where name like '%no-abc%'` ??

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya I only need rows which has no-abc but doesn't have "abc". For eg, data3 only in the above example.
where name like '%no-abc%' will give me all the rows like data1, data2, data3, data4

Comment: All no-abc rows also have abc...

Comment: @jarlh Yeah. Basically I need fields which has _no-abc, but doesn't have _abc. For eg data3 in the above example.

Comment: Now I see... Hold on.

Comment: select name from table1 where name like '%no-abc%' and in ( select name from table1 where  not like '%_abc%')

Comment: @jarlh I changed the question a little bit. Earlier I have not put the exact format. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: I am using mysql @jarlh

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this (?)

```
create table t (
    col text
);

insert into t
values
('data1_qqq_no_abc_ccc'),
('data1_qqq_abc_ccc'),
('data2_qqq_no_abc_ccc'),
('data2_qqq_abc_ccc'),
('data3_qqq_no_abc_ccc'),
('data4_qqq_no_abc_ccc'),
('data4_qqq_abc_ccc');

select f from (
    select SUBSTRING_INDEX(col, '_', 1) as f, SUBSTRING_INDEX(col, '_', -3) as s from t
) tt
group by f
having 
count(case when s = 'no_abc_ccc' then 1 end) > 0
and
count(case when s like '%qqq_abc%' then 1 end)  = 0
```

[demo](http://rextester.com/QMYKE29068)

Comment: @jarlh -  I know   this feeling ))

Comment: @OtoShavadze thanks alot for the answer. But just realized the data format is more weird than I wrote and the above answer is not working for the exact data format.
 I reedited the question. So sorry for the trouble.